# How modulo will change while moving from Left Hand Side to Right Hand Side? Example. 4a% 10 = 5. What is the value of a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have equation in the form of $ab \text{ mod } c = d$.  I want to find a value of $a$.  How can I find a value of $a$?  Please help me to find it.

Let's consider following example. $10a \text{ mod } 3 = 5$. What is the value of $a$? In this case how will you calculate a value of $a$? Please give me a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just me or did I see this question already earlier today?

Comment: Same question only but I want more explanation Mr. Matti P. Could you help me to solve this question.

Comment: I think you should consider another example. There is no remainder of $5$ when dividing by $3$.

Comment: Next time, you can edit your question directly instead of reposting. Reposting removes helpful comments from the original question, which means others cannot help you as much.

Comment: This is not a good example.  $10a\equiv5\pmod{3}\implies a\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ just by reducing $10$ and $5$ modulo $3$.

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider
$$
 ab\mod c = d
$$
In general this means, according to the definition on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation, that 
$$
 ab = d + nc \quad n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
then 
$$
 a = \frac{d + nc}{b} \quad n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
This means that you have an infinite number of solutions.

To get to a single answer, you might for example state that you want to have the first a that is positive. I can't think of a quick and solid solution for finding such an a. In that case I would simple try solve using Mathematica or similar
$$
 a = \min_n \{ x | x=\frac{d + nc}{b}, n\in\mathbb{Z}, x>0\}
$$

Comment: You need to consider whether $a,b$ are coprime to $c$.

Answer (score -1):

If $a,b$ are coprime to $c$, you can invert them in the ring of integers modulo $c$.  If not, you need to remove the common factors, then see if the solution works.  For the question in your text, $10$ and $5$ are both coprime to $3$, so we just reduce modulo $3$ to get $a=2$, though one usually uses $\equiv$ for this and appends $\pmod 3$.

For the question in your title $4$ and $10$ have a common factor $2$.  All numbers of the form $4a$ will be even $\pmod {10}$ so your equation has no solution.